# htaccess rewrite rule blog links

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have been using htaccess to remove rewrite certain URLs, however I am looking at something a little more complicated at the moment.

Our website blog (WordPress) used to have links like this:

​/blog​/postname/1387

However after redoing the website our links are now currently just

/postname

Would it be possible to redirect any uses from ​/blog​/postname/1387 and get rid of the blog and number at the end via htaccess so it just contains the postname? At the moment I have:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)/.*$ $1/
</IfModule>
```

Would love to hear any hints or tips, as this is not actually doing any redirecting, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not sure why you need `^index\.php$ - [L]` or `. /index.php [L]`. Have you tried removing those and making your rewrite rule say `RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)/.*$ $1/ [L,QSA]`?

Comment: the index rules is what WordPress added in there by default, are you sure I can remove those?

Comment: Seems redundant - `%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` is a conditional saying "Do below if file doesn't already directly exist". Then `. /index.php [L]` is a "Last" directive, which *may* be preventing `^blog/(.*)/.*$ $1/` from even firing - "If it's not a real file or directory, redirect to index.php". You should at least put your rewrite rule before that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's just do a little cleanup:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
#Turn on the RewriteEngine
RewriteEngine On

#Rewrites are all relative to /
RewriteBase /

#Explicit - If the request is for index.php, do nothing.
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

#Conditional – Unless the file or directory specifically exists,
#If the request is for the old style blog URI, redirect to new style and stop.
#Otherwise, redirect to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)/.*$ $1/ [R=301,L,QSA]
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts Stslavik, unfortunately it is not working when I try to go to

http://website.com/blog/postname/1387

It does not redirect at all, might you know why it is not doing anything at all?

Comment: Try adding `R=301,` in front of [L,QSA] as above. Testing on mamp... Since I don't really have a similar setup, it's kind of like stabbing in the dark :)